# How to print from each thread in pthreads in order?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I'm working on a program for class that takes a Floyd-Warshall directed graph (represented by a matrix) and makes a new distance matrix for each node in the graph, splitting the work of creating the new matrix among threads using pthreads.  I feel that I am right at the end, I can get the matrix to form and print, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the distance matrix to print in order (lines of matrix created by thread 0 first, then thread 1, thread 2, etc).  I use the mutex to allow each thread to print its part together without interruption, I just can't get the threads to print in order.

I was wondering if a pthread guru out there would help me out.  Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int n, totaln, **C, **D;                    /* Variable declarations */
pthread_t *threads;
pthread_mutex_t mutexprint;
long thread, threadcount;

void *LowestTerm(void* rank);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, j, k;                        /* Variable declarations */
    char filename[50];

    threadcount = atoi(argv[1]);
    threads = malloc (threadcount * sizeof(pthread_t));

    printf("Enter filename: ");             /* User enters filename for directed graph values */
    scanf("%s", filename);

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {                   /* Check whether file exists or not */
        printf("File does not exist");
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);                   /* Obtain size of matrix */

    totaln = n * n;

    C = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));          /* Allocate memory for matrix arrays */
    D = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {               /* Allocate matrices into 2D arrays */
        C[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        D[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {               /* Read matrix from file into C array */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &C[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Cost Adjacency Matrix:\n");         /* Print cost adjacency matrix */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" \n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {               /* Copy matrix from C array into D array */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            D[i][j] = C[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("Distance matrix:\n");



    for (thread = 0; thread < threadcount; thread++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[thread], NULL, LowestTerm, (void*) thread);
    }
    for (thread = 0; thread < threadcount; thread++) {
        pthread_join(threads[thread], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy (&mutexprint);
    free(threads);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}


void *LowestTerm(void* rank) {

    int i, j, k;                        /* Variable declarations */
    long mythread = (long) rank;

    int istart = ((int)mythread * n) / (int)threadcount;    /* Create matrix row start and finish parameters for each thread */
    int ifinish = ((((int)mythread + 1) * n) / (int)threadcount);

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {               /* Find shortest path for each value in each row for each of designated thread's rows */
        for (i = istart; i < ifinish; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (D[i][j] > D[i][k] + D[k][j]) {
                    D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexprint);           /* Print distance matrix */
    for (i = istart; i < ifinish; i++) {
        printf("Thread %d: ", mythread);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", D[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" \n");
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexprint);


    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: please use meaningful variable names, so we (and later on you) do not have to reverse engineer the code to figure out what is being done and what those variables mean/do

Comment: the compiler will output a warning because the argc parameter is not being used.   the code should not assume there is any parameter,  rather the code should check that argc is 2 (first parameter is the executable name)  the code, if it finds there is no parameter, should output a prompt/usage message to the user and exit

Comment: after the call to atoi(), the code needs to check that the operation was successful by checking that threadcount is >0

Comment: the returned value from malloc() 1) in C, should not be cast 2) should be checked (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the code block beginning with 'if (fp == NULL) {  1) should have the literal on the left so the compiler could catch a '=' rather than a '=='.  2) should not assure the file does not exist.  rather use perror() which will include the results from strerror().

Comment: the returned code from fscanf() (and family) should always be checked to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: a mutex needs to be initialized as the first operation.   the mutexdestroy function should not be called until after all the threads have properly exited.  I.E. the main() function needs to call pthread_join() once for each thread before destroying the mutex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to have your main thread print the entire matrix in the order you want, once all the worker threads have finished.

---

Alternatively, to have your threads print in order you can use a shared variable specifying the next thread to print (initialised to 0), paired with a condition variable:

```
pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexprint);           /* Print distance matrix */
while (next_thread != mythread)
    pthread_cond_wait(&condprint, &mutexprint);

for (i = istart; i < ifinish; i++) {
    printf("Thread %d: ", mythread);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d ", D[i][j]);
    }
    printf(" \n");
}

next_thread++;
pthread_cond_broadcast(&condprint);
pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexprint);
```

As a separate matter, I don't think your threads safely share the `D[]` array - it looks like the read from `D[k][j]` could be reading a position that is being simultaneously written by another thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
since each thread has a parameter that indicates its' rank,
the mutex could be on a global variable that indicates 
which thread/rank is to print next.
initialize it to 0.
each thread reads the global variable, after the thread
is ready to print
when the global variable matches the threads' rank, 
then the thread can:
1) lock the mutex, 
2) print, 
3) increment the global variable, 
4) unlock the mutex
5) call pthread_exit()

BTW: why are thread and threadcount defined as 'long'?
are you expecting there to be more than 4 gig threads?

at the end of function: LowestTerm()
which is a thread function.
the proper exit is not 'return value;'\
but rather phread_exit( value );
```

'

Comment: The reason why the threadid might be a long type variable, it makes it easier to cast into a pointer in pthread_create.